# How to remove index numbers in dropdown list in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
  <?php 
           $query=  $this->db->query('SELECT utility_name FROM utility2');

           $options = $query->result_array();


      //form_dropdown
     echo form_dropdown(array('name' => 'utility_name'), $options, 
     set_value('utility_name', isset($utility2->utility_name) ?    
     $utility2->utility_name : ''), lang('utility_field_utility_name'));
        ?>
```

Here is my captured image

[image: captured image]

How do I remove index numbers in dropdown list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because of the way the result set you are getting back from codeigniter is structured. Basically you just need to loop through the array and grab the field you want to print instead of the entire array. You can do this easily using the `array_column` function.

```
 $options =  array_column($options, 'utility_name');
 echo form_dropdown(array('name' => 'utility_name'),$options, 
     set_value('utility_name', isset($utility2->utility_name) ?    
     $utility2->utility_name : ''), lang('utility_field_utility_name')); ;
```

Comment: Thanks so much ;) !